# gitlab - ci for composer package

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i setup a dev-server in my homeoffice and installed gitlab via docker-compose. so far everything works fine, i can login, push commits and so on.

Now i wanted to setup a CI Pipeline to build composer packages when new tags are pushed. So i clicked the CI/CD Button and added the .gitlab-ci.yml file from the composer template. But the pipeline was only pending. So i figured i might need to register a runner first.

I installed gitlab-runner (via apt) on the same machine that runs the gitlab via docker and registered the runner with the domain and key given by gitlab (in the add runners page). I selected docker as executor, gave it a name and left everything else at its default value.

The runner is registered properly in gitlab and the ci pipeline is now working but it always fails.

The only output i have is:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11.2.0)
  on **************
Using Docker executor with image curlimages/curl:latest ...
Pulling docker image gitlab-runner-helper:11.2.0 ...
```

The contents of the gitlab-ci file are:

```yaml
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Publishes a tag/branch to Composer Packages of the current project
publish:
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  stage: build
  variables:
    URL: "$CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL://$CI_SERVER_HOST:$CI_SERVER_PORT/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/composer?job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"
  script:
    - version=$([[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]] && echo "branch=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" || echo "tag=$CI_COMMIT_TAG")
    - insecure=$([ "$CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL" = "http" ] && echo "--insecure" || echo "")
    - response=$(curl -s -w "\n%{http_code}" $insecure --data $version $URL)
    - code=$(echo "$response" | tail -n 1)
    - body=$(echo "$response" | head -n 1)
    # Output state information
    - if [ $code -eq 201 ]; then
        echo "Package created - Code $code - $body";
      else
        echo "Could not create package - Code $code - $body";
        exit 1;
      fi
```

Because i did not make any changes to the template file i suspect the gitlab-runner setup to need some configuration in order to work, maybe a group-assignment or something like that.

When running systemctl status gitlab-runner i can see:

> Failed to create container volume for /builds/{group} Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlab-runner-helper, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:166:3s)" job=15 project=34 runner=******

So i went to the runners section in gitlab and enabled the runner fot the specific project. So i could avoid the error above but the pipeline still breaks.

The output in gitlab is still the same but the gitlab-runner log is different:

> Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n

Sadly - i am not getting any furhter from here

Everytime i press the retry button for the pipeline i get the following syslog entries:

> Checking for jobs... received" job=19 repo_url="correct-url-for-repo" runner=******
> This message appears twice

> Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n
> Ignoring extra error returned from registry: unauthorized: authentication required

> Failed to create container volume for /builds/{group} Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlab-runner-helper, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:166:3s)" job=19 project=34 runner=******
> Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlab-runner-helper, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:166:3s)" job=19 project=34 runner=******
> Both messages appear twice

so either the gitlab-runner is not allowed to pull docker images or it is not allowed to access my gitlab project but i cant figure out the problem.

When running `gitlab-runner restart` as root i see the following "error"

> ERRO[0000] Docker executor: prebuilt image helpers will be loaded from /var/lib/gitlab-runner.

Can someone please help me :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Select the correct [Docker image for the runner](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). Depending where are you executing it, and probably also depending on your GitLab version. Also, manually try it before executing the pipeline:

```sh
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest
```

To use the selected image, modify the [runner's config file](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#helper-image):

```
[[runners]]
  (...)
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    (...)
    helper_image = "gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:tag"
```

Comment: I already figured it out myself, dont know if your answer would work as well but thanks for your help, i appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

The images gitlab-runner-helper, gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:11.2.0 do not exist. It seems the debian package installable in ubuntu is broken somehow... So i figured i might need to install the latest gitlab-runner version

Here is what i did: (I am on Ubuntu 20.04)

```sh
curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash
```

```sh
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-gitlab-runner.pref
Explanation: Prefer GitLab provided packages over the Debian native ones
Package: gitlab-runner
Pin: origin packages.gitlab.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
```

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#apt-pinning)

So i was able to update gitlab-runner to the latest version.

But still no success, now the service won't start without any error message, systemctl only tells mit that the process exited.

the syslog told me:

> chdir /var/lib/gitlab-runner: no such file or directory

opening /etc/init.d/gitlab-runner showed me that path as --working-directory parameter for the service.

So i created that directory and changed its ownership to gitlab-runner

This time i could run the ci pipeline!

Still got an error

> fatal: unable to access 'http://{mylocaldomain}/isat/typo3-gdpr.git/': Could not resolve host: {mylocaldomain}

Okay - dns resolution not possible because i use a local domain.

As stated [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) you can pass an extra_host to the docker executor.

To do so, simply adjust the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file and add the extra_hosts option:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "lab"
  url = "http://{localDomain}/"
  token = "******"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    extra_hosts = ["{localDomain}:{ip}"]
  [runners.cache]
```

Now i could sucessfully run the ci pipeline and my package is listed in the composer registry!